# Is there an iPhone equivalent of MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

I would like to conditionally include code for an iPhone app depending on which version of the SDK I'm compiling against.  On Mac OS X, there is the `MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` preprocessor macro which gets set to the value of the `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` build setting by the compiler.  Is there an equivalent on the iPhone?

#### Update:

I've set `IPHONE_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to 3.0 in the build settings, but Xcode is passing `-D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=20000` and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` to GCC.  Shouldn't the first one be `30000` and the second one be `-miphoneos-version-min=3.0`?  What am I doing wrong?

#### Update 2:

Looks like I wasn't doing anything wrong.  `__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED` and `-miphoneos-version-min` are both set correctly when building for a device -- it's only wrong when using the iPhone Simulator SDK.  I think it's a bug in the simulator SDK.

Comment: If you're setting those for the whole project, be aware that they may be overridden at the target level.  Make sure to set them on the target you care about.

Comment: Yup -- I was setting these at the target level.  It doesn't seem to matter what those are set to at the target and/or project level, those flags stay the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See Availability.h

```
    #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= __IPHONE_2_0
```

etc.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW156

Comment: For some reason Xcode is giving GCC -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=20000 even though I've set the iPhone Deployment Target to 3.0.  It's also passing -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 instead of -miphoneos-version-min=3.0, so something looks broken.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are preprocessor macros that are defined for each version of the OS.  For example, if `__IPHONE_OS_3_0` is defined, then you're building against the 3.0 SDK (or possibly later, I'm not certain).

Comment: That should be __IPHONE_3_0 (note: no _OS_), but I was not aware of that.  Thanks.  It would be nice if I could use __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED so it's upwards compatible, but I'm having Xcode problems with that (see update).

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, a decent work-around if such a macro does not exist, is to create 2 build targets, and in one of them add the build setting `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` with a value like `IPHONE_OS_3`.  Then in your code you can do:

```
#ifdef IPHONE_OS_3
    [foo thisMethodIsUnderNDA];
#else
    [foo oldSchoolMethod];
#endif
```